# python generate random connected graph with certain constraint on the vertex degree

Tags: python, graph

Is there any python package that could random generate connected graph (there is a path between every pair of vertices) on which each vertex has degree at most 4?

Thank you!

Comment: What do you mean by "fully connected"?

Comment: If by "fully connected" you mean [complete](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complete_graph), then there are only five non-empty graphs with this property, all shown [in this table](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complete_graph#Examples). Do you really need a library for that?

Comment: @ilim: actually I'm a math major and my thesis was on graph theory :-) ... the name we normally use is indeed "complete graph" and not "fully connected graph" but there's no randomness you can play with. There are theorems about k-vertex-connected graphs where you need to remove at least k vertices to disconnect the graph, or k edges if talking about edge-connectiveness but you need to specify k.

Comment: I changed the word "fully connected graph" to "connected graph. I want a graph in which there is a path between every two vertices and each vertex has degree at most 4.

Answer (score 0):

A simple algorithm I can think to is:

1. Start with one vertex
2. Repeat one of two random moves:

   2A) Pick a random vertex with degree less than 4 and add a new vertex connected to it

   2B) Pick two random vertices with degree less than 4 that are not connected and add an edge between them

until you've enough vertices/edges.